# Contact form. How do I get the name along with the email?

Tags: php, forms, contacts, contact-form

It's my first time trying to make a contactform. And I've got a few problems
It's works, I get the email, but I don't get the name the name field with me in the email.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" action="scripts/contact.php">
<h3>Name</h3>
<input type="text" name="name">
<h3>Email Address</h3>
<input type="text" name="email">
<h3>Message</h3>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<br/><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$to = "name@domane.com";
$subject = "Contact Us";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
$headers = "From: $email";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $name, $headers) ;
if($sent)
{print "Your mail was sent successfully"; }
else
{print "One of the field are not filled as requirred"; }
?>
```

**$name** is my problem. I've I have it in, the email comes from hostmaster@domane.com, If I delete it, everything works fine. But I wan't the name to be sent to me. How?
Or should I do it completely different?

Also, if you leave all the fields blank, the "user" doesn't get any error message, and a blank email is sent to me.

Hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Arguments to `mail()` are `to, subject, body, headers`.  You have an extra `$name` parameter there which doesn't belong.

Comment: As a side note, use `<label>`s, not `<h3>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Berkowski is correct.  What you'll need to do is add the name to your message's body (not in the sense of the input `name=` attribute, rather the body of the email).

Something like this:

```
<?php
$to = "name@domane.com";
$subject = "Contact Us";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
$headers = "From: $email";

$body = "Name: $name\r\n";
$body .= "Message: $message";

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
if($sent)
{print "Your mail was sent successfully"; }
else
{print "One of the field are not filled as requirred"; }
?>
```

**Revised:**

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" action="scripts/contact.php">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<label for="email">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<br/><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send Form" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;

$body = "Name: $name\r\n";
$body .= "Message: $message";

$to = "name@domane.com";
$from = "automailer@mydomainname.com (Website Automailer)";
$subject = "Contact Us";
$headers =  "From: $from\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $email ($name)";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
if($sent) { echo "Your mail was sent successfully"; }
else { echo "One of the field are not filled as requirred"; }
?>
```

Comment: @Plambech I just added some more complete HTML and php to my answer.  With the html, I closed your input tags and gave them each a unique `id=`.  Then I changed your `H3`'s to `<label>`s and set them to the respective input's ID's (this way you can click the label to bring the input to focus).  With the php, I reconfigured the from and set up a reply-to.  The "from" address should be use the same domain as the site (and can be an arbitrary email address).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [`mail`](http://php.net/mail) function documentation on php.net.

Have a look at the function signature:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Now you're placing `$name` as the "`$additional_headers`" argument. You should pass `$name` and any extra relevant data in a `$message` argument instead.

Having that said, here's the correct code to send a message:

```
$sent = mail($to, $subject, "A message from $name: $message", $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read more about how email messages are constructed. Instead of just putting a user defined message in there you probably want to specify some email headers, containing a more beautiful `FROM:` and the like...